# How to enable Android permissions with adb for all devices

Tags: java, android, adb

I want all Android permissions to be activated automatically when installing the app.

I know I can enable all permissions on my device by installing the apk via adb.

```
adb install -g test.apk
```

Can I use this method for all devices or is there a way to enable permissions automatically?

Comment: In what context?  On your own device?  You can do some hacky stuff to adb to make sure it always gets called with -g from the command line.  In a play store app?  No, and it shouldn't-  that would be a security breach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to root your android device in order to provide all the available permissions for your app. Every time, activating the ADB shell for apk installation of the app is not viable. In order to avoid that, you can simply write this piece of code:

```
private void AllowPerm()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Allow all permissions: Prompting User...");
        
        // Defining the requierd permissions in the below String array.
        
        String[] perm={Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,};
        
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                perm[0])== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                perm[1])==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                perm[2])==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestperm(MainActivity.this,perm,REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestpermResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] perm, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        AllowPerm();
    }
```

You can give your desired permissions in the String array by looking at this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

You can also perform the above step by manually declaring the `PERMISSIONS` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` (Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro))